How to debug x86 Assembly Code on Arm64 using GDB?
I am learning x86 Assembly. I want to debug my code with GDB but the problem is my device is Arm64 so it gives me errors like "cannot access memory 0x1000".
I tried using qemu-i386 gdb run-test and it didn't work obviously because the gdb executable is not x86.
So like we do with ld by using ld.lld is there any way to debug x86 assembly code on Arm64 with gdb?

You will need a cross-compiled gdb or run gdb in another qemu if that works. Of course you could just have a full blown virtual machine with an x86 linux inside.

@Jester How about trying to run a x86 executable of gdb using qemu-i386?

That was the second option I listed. Problem is gdb depends on a ton of shared libraries ... probably easiest to use a linux VM.

@Jester: I seem to recall that multiarch GCC is a thing, so a native GDB executable can debug native ARM64 executables or connect to an i386 QEMU, if built with multiarch support.  (QEMU can act as a GDB-remote.)  So basically this is the opposite problem of How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU? which mentions gdb-multiarch, and How to run a single line of assembly, then see [R1] and condition flags . (Those are about ARM binaries on x86 systems.)
